# Can Paypal subscription be paused and started back up again, where it left off

Tags: paypal, subscription

We're building a marketplace website where vendors can have a business listing on a Paypal mthly subscription basis.

All vendors get an admin when signing up.

Query :- Could we set it up so a Paypal subscription could be paused by a vendor by clicking a button in their admin, . . . pause their subscription for an indefinite period, . . . and then the subscriber clicks a button in their admin and starts the subscription up again seamlessly without having to do any resigning up anywhere?

Scenario : We have a Basic Listing (free) and  Premium Listing (subscription), they sign up for the Premium, but want to pause it by clicking a button 'Downgrade to Basic Listing" where their subscription is paused and their listing is downgraded to Basic Listing, . . . but then they want to turn Premium back on (click a button called “Turn on Premium Listing Again”, and get back their remaining mthly subscription time that was still owing for the month which would push their mthly rollover time out, . . . or if they want to turn it on after the month is up and still get back the time they paid for but didn't end up getting as a Premium Listing?

Is any scenario like this possible? What’s the best way to handle this?

Comment: You should direct this question to PayPal, but I'm certain the answer is 'no'. Just get rid of the 'downgrade' button and let them start with a free trial that automatically becomes paid unless they cancel it. That's the model PayPal provides: use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate the newest [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), there is a call to [Suspend Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#suspend-subscription).

Presumably it can then be [Activated](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#activate-subscription) once more (you can test this)

---

By the way, as far as I am aware the newest version of the Subscriptions API and underlying Catalog/Products and newest format Billing Plan/Agreement APIs (which are not the same as previous versions of the same-named API calls) are not supported by any of the current PayPal SDKs -- so to use so if you do integrate this new [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), you need your own direct REST API HTTPS calls, to first exchange a clientid:secret for an oauth2 `access_token` and call each endpoint.

Comment: This is very helpful, thankyou, I did search paypal for an answer but couldn't find anything, didn't directly query them though. This could be what we're looking for though.

Comment: I'm just doing some preliminary research to get my head around what we may have to do for this, I'm the designer/owner of the site but not the developer, I apologise if I am misusing this forum!